# Sort list of tuples by value furthest from zero

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, sorting

```
lst = list((('one',10),('two',-30),('three',20)))
```

I'd like to implement something similar to:

```
lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1] , reverse = True)
```

However, I'd like the order to be in absolute value order without losing the sign.  Applied to the lst the output should be:

('two',-30)
('three',20)
('one',10)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort by absolute value, sort by absolute value...

```
lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: abs(x[1]), reverse=True)
```

This makes `lst`

```
[('two', -30), ('three', 20), ('one', 10)]
```

Comment: doh.  I should have known better.